# Looking for metro style button(s) CSS

Tags: css, microsoft-metro

I'm looking for very simple CSS samples for Metro Style Button design (pure CSS w/o JS).
I've already found metroui.co.ua but can't use that since i can't embed additional JS or html tags/classes into project (i know, i know..) all i need is PURE css. 
Thanks.

Comment: your try????some code or foddle

Comment: Are you serious? What's so painfully hard about setting a solid background colour? If you're trying to do something more complex, state exactly what you're trying to do in your question

Comment: twitter-bootstrap 3 has the metric look and feel http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a resource for a CSS only solution

`http://pixelsdaily.com/resources/html-css/css-windows-8-metro-buttons/`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/ksM5Y/